# Need help to install a rpm format program into CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, rpm, yum

I wish to install the Lan Messenger from https://lanmessenger.github.io/ into my CentOS 7 and I downloaded the rpm format installer "lmc-1.2.37.x86_64_min.rpm".

Because there is only libcrypto.so.10, after installed the lacking-from-existed-yum-repos dependence libcrypto.so.1.0.0 from http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/openmandriva/4.0/x86_64/main/release/lib64crypto1.0.0-1.0.2r-2.x86_64.html. I run

`$ sudo yum install lmc-1.2.37.x86_64_min.rpm`

But it ends with the error message below:

```
Transaction Summary
=============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package  (+15 Dependent packages)
Upgrade             (  3 Dependent packages)

Total size: 32 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction check error:
  file / from install of lmc-1.2.37-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file /usr from install of lmc-1.2.37-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin from install of lmc-1.2.37-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib from install of lmc-1.2.37-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share from install of lmc-1.2.37-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/share/applications from install of lmc-1.2.37-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package filesystem-3.2-21.el7.x86_64
......(etc)
```

I checked the rpm file by

`$ rpm -qpl lmc-1.2.37.x86_64_min.rpm`

The beginning of the output is below:

```
/
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/lmc
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/lmc
/usr/lib/lmc/COPYING
/usr/lib/lmc/lan-messenger
/usr/lib/lmc/lang
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/ar_SA.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/bg_BG.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/de_DE.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/en_US.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/es_ES.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/fr_FR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/it_IT.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/ko_KR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/ml_IN.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/pt_BR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/ro_RO.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/ru_RU.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/sl_SI.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/ar_SA.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/de_DE.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/es_ES.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/fr_FR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/ko_KR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/pt_BR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/system/sl_SI.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/lang/tr_TR.qm
/usr/lib/lmc/liblmcapp.so.2
/usr/lib/lmc/lmc.rcc
/usr/lib/lmc/lmc.sh
......(etc)
```

It is strange that items such as "/", "/usr", "/usr/bin", etc are in the rpm file, I feel.

Need I add some extra options in my "sudo yum install ..." command? Or did I download an rpm file that is not suitable for CentOS 7? Or I need to do other things?

Could you give me some advice? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is strange that items such as "/", "/usr", "/usr/bin", etc are in the rpm file, I feel.

Indeed, those are incorrect. It appears that the author used [alien](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/10/26/use-alien-to-convert-deb-to-rpm-and-rpm-to-deb/) for converting deb to rpm, and the resulting RPM package has got erroneous file locations included.

> Or I need to do other things?

Without actually rebuilding the package, I think you can succeed to fix the current package with [`rpmrebuild`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rpmrebuild):

```
rpmrebuild --edit-spec --package lmc-1.2.37.x86_64_min.rpm
```

Then adjust the `%files` section by removing erroneous locations, and then you will be able to install the resulting/modified package.

Comment: Thank you for answering. With your answer and noticing this package is from github.io rather than github.com, I doubt it is not good software. If it is and many people use it, this situation will be for sure not existed. I am still new to the Linux environment and fix it is too hard for me. I believe that I need to seek another good software similar to it. Thank you all the same. I will try your approach someday later when I learned enough prerequisites.